# Transparent background in CoreGraphics

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

I am trying to get a transparent background in CG but it keeps coming out black.

I have the following code:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        DLog(@">>> Alloc: DrawingCanvas [0x%X]", (unsigned int)self);
        [self setOpaque:NO];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect frame = rect;
    int counter = 3;

    CGContextClearRect(context, frame);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, frame);
}
```

How do I get this code to show a transparent background?

Comment: Did you find a solution?  If so, please share it by answering your own question.

Answer (score 4):

With that setup and as long as you don't set `clearsContextBeforeDrawing` to NO, the background should already be transparent when your `drawRect:` method is called. Remove the CGContextClearRect and other drawing calls.

Comment: I will be using the same (similar) code in another place where I get a context passed in and I will have to clear it each time, so I don't see that I will be able to remove the call to 'CGContextClearRect' - unless I can clear it in a different way?

Answer (score 4):

You could simply remove these lines :

```
CGContextClearRect(context, frame);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, frame);
```

As long as you have set opaque to NO and clearColor as backgroundColor everything should be fine.

Be careful when drawing since your other drawing code may fill the background entirely (take care of `[path fill]` things in a non-clipped context).

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and the solution was to set the `backgroundColor` property of the UIView which I was drawing in, from the parent view's class. I didn't need any code to clear the background in the UIView's class where the drawing happens.

```
myDrawingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```